# HttpSendHttpResponse no data sent

Tags: http, winapi, smalltalk, httpserver

I am implementing a web server using `Ms http server api` v2 (in synchronous mode), and I am trying to test it from a web browser.

I send a GET request from the browser to http://localhost:50000/uri/ and my application receives it correctly. Then I send the response, with some data in a (`HTTP_DATA_CHUNK`) using the `HttpSendHttpResponse`, and I get 131 bytes sent. However, the browser is not receiving any data.
I have also tested it with `wininet` client with the same result.

This is my send response code (Smalltalk):

```
sendResponse: aString
    | data response sent id return |
    data := HTTP_DATA_CHUNK external 
    data 
        DataChunkType: 0;
        pBuffer: aString copyToExternalMemory;
        BufferLength: aString size.
    response := HTTP_RESPONSE_V2 external.
    response
        version1;
        StatusCode: HTTP_STATUS_OK;
        reason: 'Ok';
        ContentType: 'text/html';
        EntityChunkCount: 1;
        dataChunk: data.
    sent := ExternalLong external.
    return := HttpServerDLL current
        HttpSendHttpResponse: handle
        RequestId: request id
        Flags: 0
        pHttpResponse: response asParameter
        pCachePolicy: 0
        pBytesSent: sent asParameter
        pReserved2: 0
        Reserved3: 0
        pOverlapped: 0
        pLogData: 0.
    return = 0 ifFalse: [^self osError: return].
    ^sent asInteger
```

Any idea about why if the HttpSendHttpResponse function success and indicates that n bytes has been sent, the client doesn't receive the data?

Thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: In case you are unaware you would not see this in a browser (outside of the Network Inspector) as `HttpSendHttpResponse` is for HTTP headers, `HttpSendResponseEntityBody` is for data

Comment: Thanks @AlexK., I understand that the `HttpSendHttpResponse` can also send data in one call. I am following the MSDN sample [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364640(v=vs.85).aspx], and there, some text is sent as an answer in a data chunk buffer using `HttpSendHttpResponse`. Anyway, I will try by calling `HttpSendResponseEntityBody`.

Comment: I didn't know it could do that, [MSDN "Remarks"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says *"The HttpSendHttpResponse function is used to create and send a response header, and the HttpSendResponseEntityBody function can be used to send entity-body data as required."*

Comment: Same result using `HttpSendHttpResponse` with no data and Flags = `HTTP_SEND_RESPONSE_FLAG_MORE_DATA` and then calling `HttpSendResponseEntityBody` with the data and Flags = `HTTP_SEND_RESPONSE_FLAG_DISCONNECT`. The browser shows an empty page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the problem. I had an error in the alignment of    `HTTP_DATA_CHUNK` structure since some fields are 8 bytes aligned so, the data pointer was in a bad offset. 
With this fixed, I have tried again with just the `HttpSendHttpResponse` without success, and then using both, `HttpSendHttpResponse` for the headers and `HttpSendHttpResponseEntityBody` for the data, and it works! Maybe the [MSDN sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364640(v=vs.85).aspx) is outdated. There, the data is sent with the response in a single call to `HttpSendHttpResponse`.

Thank you very much, Sebastian